# saaj.soap to xml.soap castException in Glassfish

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

I have a working solution that has a webservice deployed on GlassFish, and when a client sends an XML request to the webservice I extract the first child from the SOAPBody.  This works fine with GlassFish 3.1.1 and java runtime 1.6.0_06-b02 running on Windows 7, Server 2003 and Server 2008 R2.

I have been asked to deploy the solution on GlassFish 3.1.2 and java runtime 1.7.0_09 running on Ubuntu 12.10

When running using my test harness that has no whitespace in the XML of the SOAPEnvelope both the 3.1.1 and 3.1.2 systems work correctly, however, if I use SoapUI to send a message containing whitespace the Window installations work correctly, while the Ubuntu version raises a cast exception.

When I attempt to run the following code fragment (a message handler assigned to the web service):

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext messageContext) {
    SOAPElement requestElt = (SOAPElement) messageContext.getMessage().getSOAPBody().getFirstChild();
    // Do things here
}
```

When the Envelope contains whitespace the following exception is thrown:

```
com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.TextImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement
```

Can anyone explain this issue for me please?

Answer (score 0):

After updating a Windows machine to jdk1.7.0_13 and GlassFish 3.1.2, I got the same issue that I could not hadle SOAP messages with white space.

I have no idea why this is, and whether the issue is with the JDK or GlassFish, and whether it is a problem introduced or tightening of XML processing.

The upshot is that I have now created a routine that you pass the SOAPBody too which iterates over the ChildElements until it finds an Element rather than a Node.

If you are reading this it is probably not what you want to hear, but it works currently for me.